# Old iPhone for games only

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 10 but saved my iPhone 6 for grandchildren to play games on. How do I stop messages from appearing on the old phone and the log for incoming calls? I’m hesitant to delete my Apple ID since I purchase games occasionally with it. Is there a way I can still use the App Store and stop the messages from appearing?

Answer (score 1):

The officially supported way is to use Family Sharing. You create a child Apple ID using your account, and you will maintain parental control over the child account, including App Store, iTunes and Apple Books purchases. It will have access to all your apps and music, and you will have the opportunity to approve any purchases your grandchild makes.

### Create an Apple ID for your child

> Use the steps below to create an Apple ID for your child, then add
>   them to your family group. After you add your child to your family
>   group, they will have their own Apple ID that they can use on any
>   Apple device. Your email address is the rescue email address for your
>   child’s account, and you can use it with the security questions you
>   provided to reset a forgotten password.
>
> If the child already has a Game Center account, but not an Apple ID,
>   you don't need to create a new account for them. Just search for their
>   nickname instead.

1. Go to Settings > [your name] > Family Sharing > Add Family Member >
   Create a Child Account > Next. If you're using iOS 10.2 or earlier,
   go to Settings > iCloud > Family.
2. Enter your child's birthday and tap Next. Be sure to enter the
   correct date.
3. Review the Parent Privacy Disclosure and tap Agree.
4. Enter the requested information for your payment method and tap
   Next. If you don't have a payment method on file, you need to add
   one.
5. Enter your child's name, tap Next, then create their Apple ID
   (username@icloud.com) and tap Next. Tap Create.
6. Follow the onscreen instructions to set a password, choose security
   questions, and set up your child's account. Choose passwords and
   security questions that you can both remember.
7. Turn on Ask to Buy to approve all iTunes, Apple Books, and App Store
   purchases initiated by your child. You will be responsible for all
   charges to your account. Tap Next.
8. Review the Terms and Conditions. Tap Agree.

Source: [Family Sharing and Apple ID for your child](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084)

Now you should be free to set up the iPhone 6 with the new child Apple ID. Either:

- reset the device **Settings > General >  Reset > Erase All Content and Settings** then sign back in with the new ID; or
- sign out of iCloud, iTunes and App Store, FaceTime, iMessage etc. then sign back in with the new ID.

Answer (score 0):

Sign out of mail, Messages and FaceTime - leave the App Store signed in is the easy way to accomplish what you ask.

Open the settings app, tap to each and tap to sign out.

- https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/

Or you could erase the device and then only sign in for App Store or make a “family” account that shares purchasing but is it’s own AppleID.

Answer (score 0):

I would signed out of Apple ID but then signed in to App Store.